# How to select element by the last part of an attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, anchor, href

I want to add `target="_blank"` for only the `<a>` element where the last part of `href` is `page2.aspx`. How I can do that using jQuery? I tried this:

```
$j("a[href='page2.aspx']").attr('target', '_blank'); // not sure if it works?
```

```html
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page1.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page2.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page3.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page4.aspx">My Site</a>
```

I could not access `<a>` like below because of variation(language) changes every time page renders.

```
$j("a[href='/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page2.aspx']").attr('target', '_blank');
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try `$=`, it works in CSS that way at least. Or simply add a class name to that specific `<a>` tag?

Comment: due to some resons, i could not add class name to that specific url because all this html is generated by custom server side code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector:

```
$j("a[href$='page2.aspx']").prop('target', '_blank');
```

```js
$("a[href$='page2.aspx']").prop('target', '_blank');

// here's something that makes a visible difference so you 
// can see the element is targeted properly
$("a[href$='page2.aspx']").css('color', '#C00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page1.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page2.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page3.aspx">My Site</a>
<a href="/en-gb/mypage/Pages/page4.aspx">My Site</a>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't see any example with ends with selector, Can you please write any example for demonstration?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I added a link to the documentation in the question: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: I also added a snippet so you can see a working example

Comment: I mean ends with ($=) did not work in my case with .prop property but works fine with .attr() property.

Comment: Are you using an old version of jQuery? `prop()` was added in 1.7. You should really, *really* update your jQuery version if this is the case.